# Change MUI time picker to digital clock, within a DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datetime, material-ui

I want to use MUI DateTimePicker which has two steps, where we first pick the date from a calendar, and then pick the time using the DigitalClock time picker. I have a working component, but it uses the Analog Clock picker for the time picker view. How can i simply change this to use the digital clock picker within the component? Only to be used on desktop.

It looks lke this for now:

> `<DesktopDateTimePicker {...rest} {...field} inputRef={ref} disabled={disabled} inputFormat="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" renderInput={(inputProps) => ( <TextField {...inputProps} error={!!error} onBlur={onBlur} helperText={error?.message} /> )} />`

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import DesktopDateTimePicker from '@mui/lab/DesktopDateTimePicker';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns'; // You might use a different adapter

const MyDateTimePicker = ({ field, inputRef, disabled, error, onBlur, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <DesktopDateTimePicker
      {...rest}
      {...field}
      inputRef={inputRef}
      disabled={disabled}
      inputFormat="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
      views={['day', 'month', 'year', 'hours', 'minutes']} // Add 'hours' and 'minutes' for time selection
      components={{
        OpenPickerIcon: () => null, // Remove date picker icon
        TimePicker: () => <DigitalClock />, // Use DigitalClock for time 
      }}
      renderInput={(inputProps) => (
        <TextField
          {...inputProps}
          error={!!error}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          helperText={error?.message}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default MyDateTimePicker;
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get two errors with your code though. Firstly <DigitalClock/> isn't found, and does not exist in my MUI structure (idk why). And I also get this error on on "TimePicker: ()" within "components":

Type '{ OpenPickerIcon: () => null; TimePicker: () => JSX.Element; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<DesktopDateTimePickerSlotsComponent>'.
 DesktopDateTimePicker.d.ts(15, 5): The expected type comes from property 'components' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &

Comment: I found out it is because we are using v5 of MUI, and it does not seem to have digital clock. I'll see if we can migrate.